# How did the giant travel across the sea to Castle Black?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* episode (S05E08) where Jon Snow, the now Lord Commander of the Night's Watch reaches the Wildling's camp across the sea with boats to take the Wildlings to the south of the wall he reaches there with many small boats with him to take the free folks back to the safe place.

The boats were not big enough to carry a giant, and all they had was boats, even a medium size ship can't carry that giant (and there were no ships at all), still the giant reaches Castle Black with the them.

[image]

I can't understand how did the giant manage to travel through the sea to reach Castle Black without any boat or ship.

It's not that I am against the Giant going south of the wall :P But really how did it travel the sea?

Comment: I tried to streamline the images a bit in order to make the question more readable. Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: Seeing as he was wading out to the ships and he couldn't be tall enough to walk the whole way, I just assumed he could swim

Comment: I thought they did have ships - didn't they borrow Stannis's fleet? I thought that was where the landing boats were taking them. I assumed the giant either sat on a boat or swam using it as a buoyancy aid...

Comment: Probably. I remember Jon Snow asking  Stannis for his Fleet, though it wasn't shown in any of the scenes, only small boats.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Don't you count [this fleet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/twONp.jpg) as ships or something? They're clearly loading the longboats aboard them which fits the classic definition of ship.

Comment: I thought he walked across sea. He may have swimmed also , however very little chance of gaint knowing how to swim. In general, there leaved beyond the wall and looking at his size, I don't think he needed to swim in rivers :-). All this is speculation, nothing shown explicitly in TV show.

Comment: @CrowTRobot Oh, didn't see those clearly. Anyways it still looks very small to carry that giant.

Comment: Well the wildlings marched through the tunnel and through Castle Black, so the ships must have landed north of the wall. The giant probably just waded in the water far enough that the zombies couldn't reach him, and went back onto land a bit south where the zombies couldn't see him. Then he walked the rest of the way with the rest of the wildlings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [GOT WIKI](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wun_Weg_Wun_Dar_Wun) he definitely reached out to ships:

> Being too large for the rowboats, he simply wades out into the bay for a long distance (not drowning due to his great height) **to reach the larger ships waiting off shore**. He is one of the few wildlings to escape the Massacre at Hardhome, and the fleet travels back to the Wall.

Now he either took a ride or tied and pulled by a group of ships.

Comment: That doesn't exactly prove he travelled on these "larger ships", this sentence is simply a description of what we saw in the show (Wun Wun walking towards the ships). That said, I agree it's the most plausible theory - I don't think he walked, there's no chance he could march as fast as a ship in full sail.

Comment: Yup I agree!! but per wiki it is sure he reached out for larger ship. So he either took a ride or just hung through the ship to reach the Wall. Let me modify my answer.